# function to create multiple maps using geom_sf fails

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm creating a function I will use to make a series of maps. I've done this before with `tmap` but this is my first time using `geom_sf` and I seem to be encountering an error in my function call I can figure out.

Here is the successful code of one map I want to create:

```
  GA <- ggplot(data = GA_data_shape) + 
    geom_sf(aes(fill = rel), 
            color = NA) +
    scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma") +
    theme_void() +
    labs(fill = "Rainfall (inches)", 
         title = "Georgia", 
         subtitle = "Relative rainfall") + 
    theme(legend.position = "right",
          legend.title = element_text(size = 8, 
                                      face = "bold"),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
          plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", 
                                    color = "black"),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "italic", 
                                       color = "black"))
  
  GA
```

Here is the function and the function call to create the same map. I want to use the function to create a series of maps by simply changing the variable and titles:

```
mapping <- function(variable, ltitle, ptitle, stitle){
  
  ggplot(data = GA_data_shape) + 
    geom_sf(aes(fill = variable), 
            color = NA) +
    scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma") +
    theme_void() +
    labs(fill = ltitle,
         title = ptitle,
         subtitle = stitle) +
    theme(legend.position = "right",
          legend.title = element_text(size = 8, 
                                      face = "bold"),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
          plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", 
                                    color = "black"),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "italic", 
                                       color = "black"))
}

# GA distance from protest
rainfall <- mapping(variable = rel, 
                    ltitle = "Rainfall (inches)", 
                    ptitle = "Georgia", 
                    stitle = "Relative rainfall")

rainfall
```

Unfortunately, the function call just above returns the following error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): fill = variable. Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?

I don't understand because the fist code chunk runs and is almost exactly the same as the second but the function call fails. I assume there is something under the hood in the function call I'm doing wrong, but I can't figure it out. I've checked and GA_data_shape is an `sf object` and the variable `rel` is correct. I've even tried several different variables to no avail. Can anyone help me understand why this function isn't working?

thanks

Comment: Try with `geom_sf(aes(fill = {{variable}}), ...)`. Otherwise ggplot will look for a column with name `variable`.

Comment: @stefan yep that did it! Thanks so much. I've noticed this is a new feature to the `tidyverse` that I've had to use in other `dplyr` commands.  How do I identify when I need to use it and when I don't?